# Impedir que divs repetidas sejam exibidas

Tags: javascript

Utilizo o código abaixo para exibir uma `div` aleatória da classe `destino`, porém, quando executo a função, muitas vezes a mesma `div` ou a `div` anterior se repetem. Há como consertar?

```
        function destino() {
            var E = document.getElementsByClassName("destino");
            var m = E.length;
            var n = parseInt(Math.random()*m);
            for (var i=m-1;i>=0;i--) {
                var e = E[i];
                e.style.display='none';
            }
            E[n].style.display='';
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código está a mostrar várias `divs` aleatórias da classe destino de cada vez porque tem um `for` a percorrer de um determinado numero até `0`.

Como solução ao seu problema pode guardar num array os que ainda não foram mostrados, chamando-lhe por exemplo `disponiveis`, e buscar a `div` aleatória para mostrar dai:

```
//obter os divs existentes e guardar num array os que ainda não foram sorteados
let disponiveis = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("destino"));

function destino() {
    if (disponiveis.length == 0) return; //se não existem mais sai

    const n = parseInt(Math.random()*disponiveis.length); //sorteia apenas 1
    disponiveis[n].style.display=''; //mostra o sorteado

    disponiveis.splice(n,1); //remove do array o que foi sorteado
}
```

Repare que troquei o obter dos elementos para `Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("destino"))` para ficar com um array em vez de um `HTMLCollection`, o que me permite depois usar `splice` para remover um elemento.

Exemplo:

```js
let disponiveis = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("destino"));

function destino() {
  if (disponiveis.length == 0) return;

  const n = parseInt(Math.random() * disponiveis.length);
  disponiveis[n].style.display = 'block';
  disponiveis.splice(n, 1);
}

document.getElementById("sortear").onclick = function(){
  destino();
};
```

```css
.destino {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="destino">D1</div>
<div class="destino">D2</div>
<div class="destino">D3</div>
<div class="destino">D4</div>
<div class="destino">D5</div>
<div class="destino">D6</div>
<div class="destino">D7</div>

<button id="sortear">Sortear</button>
```

No exemplo se quiséssemos ficar com a ordem em que foi sorteado seria melhor adicionar os sorteados a outro `div`:

```js
let disponiveis = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("destino"));
const sorteados = document.getElementById("sorteados"); //div para sorteados

function destino() {
  if (disponiveis.length == 0) return;

  const n = parseInt(Math.random() * disponiveis.length);
  disponiveis[n].style.display = 'block';
  sorteados.appendChild(disponiveis[n]); //adicionar aos sorteados
  disponiveis.splice(n, 1);
}

document.getElementById("sortear").onclick = function(){
  destino();
};
```

```css
.destino {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="destino">D1</div>
<div class="destino">D2</div>
<div class="destino">D3</div>
<div class="destino">D4</div>
<div class="destino">D5</div>
<div class="destino">D6</div>
<div class="destino">D7</div>

<button id="sortear">Sortear</button>
<div id="sorteados"></div><!-- div para colocar os sorteados-->
```